# Is there any way to combine views block to homepage?

Tags: views

Is there any way to combine views block to homepage?

Example:
I created different views blocks like team, about us, portfolio, services and sliders.

The first homepage has about us, portfolio and services.

The second homepage has team, services and sliders.

I can set one of them to front page without adjust the arrangement of views block in structure/blocks.

How do I make the changes of frontpage more efficiently with just change it to first homepage or second homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which Drupal you are using. But the procedure is pretty same for D7 & D8.

---

### Normal Drupal Approach:

**1.** Create a block/views-block and set it's visibility to  as shown below, do it for all blocks which you want to show on front.

> [image]

**2.** Go to Structures/blocks & place all views-blocks/normal-blocks under the `content` region as shown in following image, in order in which you want to display.

> [image]

**3.** Front page: Now, all three blocks with their content are visible only on the front page as shown below.

> [image]

For Second-home page: Do the same thing as above just apply the visibility to `second-home-page` url in the first step.

---

### Using Panels module

You can use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module to get more settings, but if your purpose serves with above approach, do not add extra module in your site. But with Panels module, you can achieve any display setting what you can think of.